# How can I correct this behavior on google line chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to plot two series using Google chart, the series does not have the pts
and in the graph i got a discontinuous line for one serie (see the pic below)

[image]

Can any one know how to fix this please.

Comment: you need to post the code you are using before we can help.

Comment: I added an example of my code in this link
http://plnkr.co/edit/xInQNO866cliX7OYsQhO?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the size of the points by using either the `pointSize` option or the `series.<series index>.pointSize` option.  Both will take an integer for the point size in pixels.  The `pointSize` option controls the point size for all series (default is `0`).  The `series` option overrides the default for specific series.

```
pointSize: 3
```

or

```
series: {
    0: {
        pointSize: 3 // first series
    },
    1: {
        pointSize: 5 // second series
    }
}
```

To eliminate the gap in the data, you have to set the `interpolateNulls` option to `true`:

```
interpolateNulls: true
```

Comment: thanks asgallant, this is exactly what i'm looking for.